# How to add User edit link in main menu

Tags: routes, navigation

Site  [link](http://www.kavings.com/coupon/user/9/edit)

here, in this 9 is the user id.it is different according to register users.

When add link in main menu there is an option Path textbox
in that text box if i add "**user/9/edit**" then link is created but here 9 is login user id. then it is accessible only whose user id 9. but other not access.
I want to add link dynamic which user are login then that user access that user edit page.user/*/edit

Comment: have you tried user/*/edit in main menu

Answer (score 1):

Install [me aliases](https://www.drupal.org/project/me) module.

> Provides shortcut paths to current user's pages, eg user/me, blog/me,
>   user/me/edit, tracker/me etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Menu token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token)

> Menu Token module provides tokens, that could be used in title or in
>   path of menu items (links). For example, if you create a menu item
>   with path: "user/[current-user:uid]", the url will be changed "on fly"
>   to: "user/1" (assuming you are user 1).

or you can do it by using [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter.
 * Check access for forum menu item.
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['forum']['access callback'] = '_accesscheck';
}
/**
 * Callback to disallow access for the anonymous user.
 */
function _accesscheck(){
  global $user;
  return $user->uid;
}
```